# Codeigniter redirect to custom view when Unable to select database

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter

I'm trying to find a way to redirect my codeigniter application to a custom link (controller/method) where i can custom the content from my views folder only when this error occured.

```
A Database Error Occurred

Unable to select the specified database: *******

Filename: core/Loader.php

Line Number: 347
```

I tried to custom the file errors/error_db.php, but it's not what i want, because the file includes all database errors and i want to keep it intact, or if there is a way to do an if-else in this file to redirect only if this error : "Unable to select the specified database" occured.

Comment: did you load `database` library?

Comment: Yes i load it in controller by $this->load->database($config); with a custom $config

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this with your "errors/error_db.php"

Note that redirect function needs url library to be loaded already.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Database Error</title>
<style type="text/css">

::selection{ background-color: #E13300; color: white; }
::moz-selection{ background-color: #E13300; color: white; }
::webkit-selection{ background-color: #E13300; color: white; }

body {
    background-color: #fff;
    margin: 40px;
    font: 13px/20px normal Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #4F5155;
}

a {
    color: #003399;
    background-color: transparent;
    font-weight: normal;
}

h1 {
    color: #444;
    background-color: transparent;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #D0D0D0;
    font-size: 19px;
    font-weight: normal;
    margin: 0 0 14px 0;
    padding: 14px 15px 10px 15px;
}

code {
    font-family: Consolas, Monaco, Courier New, Courier, monospace;
    font-size: 12px;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    border: 1px solid #D0D0D0;
    color: #002166;
    display: block;
    margin: 14px 0 14px 0;
    padding: 12px 10px 12px 10px;
}

#container {
    margin: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #D0D0D0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 8px #D0D0D0;
}

p {
    margin: 12px 15px 12px 15px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <h1><?php echo $heading; ?></h1>
        <?php 
        $pos = strpos($message, "Unable to select the specified database");

        if ($pos === false) {
            echo $message;
        }else{
            redirect("controller/method");
        }
        ?>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I replaced redirect("controller/method"); by echo("controller/method"); to test your script. The probleme here is that the url helper is autoloaded in autoload.php and don't work. I tried to use $CI =& get_instance(); $CI->load->helper('url'); but don't work too. 
Any idea?

Comment: use `header("Location: controller/method");` instead of `redirect("controller/method");`

Comment: No error message. i put echo $pos; header("Location: controller/method"); the result is that echo 3 (the value of $pos) and don't redirect me to "controller/method"

Comment: replace `redirect("controller/method");` with `?><script>window.location.href='<?php echo base_url('controller/method'); ?>';</script><?php`

Comment: That don't work because the condition executed each time the page loaded, the $pos = strpos($message, "Unable to select the specified database"); return 3 in each load of the page because in each load database is not selected. So the page still in a loop

Comment: Why don't you put your "custom content" here in else block?

Comment: Yes That's exactly what I did. thank you for the help. I'm waiting for other answers if any better ideas comes. else if nothing found i will mark your answer as the most helpfull in finding the solution. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Just add a test when connecting to the db

```
$db = $this->database->load('...');
$connected = $db->initialize();
if (!$connected) 
{
  //load view, redirect....
}
```

Comment: I load the database in MY-Controller in this way $this->load->database($config); with a custom $config. IF the database is set, $connected value equal 1, and i don't be redirected, But when db is not set, automaticly it show error message, it's like if when the database not set the app don't execute your if-else, and show debug. But when i put 'db_debug' => FALSE, $connected equal 1 when database is set and also when it's not set.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the application is multi tenant, same code base with different database, had a link between URL subdomain and its db. Hence in the login controller added mysqli_connect to check if the database exists, if not redirected the user to the register page.